# CakePHP 3 validation provider

Tags: php, cakephp

Location: src/Model/Validation/XmlValidator.php

```
namespace App\Model\Validation;

class XmlValidation {
    public static function isValidXml($check) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in my model in validationDefault() i have:

```
$validator->provider('upload', App\Model\Validation\XmlValidator::class);

$validator->add('raport', 'notValidXml', [
     'rule' => 'isValidXml',
     'message' => 'yourErrorMessage',
     'provider' => 'upload'
]);
```

I still getting: Unable to call method "isValidXml" in "upload" provider for field "raport"

What do I do wrong?

Comment: `XmlValidator != XmlValidation`. Is that just a typo in the example that you've posted here?

Comment: It's just a typo. Sory.

Comment: OK. I did it :D
I created function in my model and as a provider I set 'table'
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#validation-providers

Comment: I'd say it's better to delete the question then, as it won't be of help for future readers.

Comment: Better than deleting the question, let's write the answer and leave it for other people that may also have this confusion. I found very little information on the official docs. This question actually helped me.

Answer (score 0):

As @ndm said, `XmlValidator != XmlValidation` so the problem is just a typo.